Heavy Water (D2O) vs Water (H2O) in Nuclear Reactors
Some Nuclear Power Plants use D20 whilst some use H20 as moderators.
And all nuclear power plants which are for commercial use are 1st stage reactors.
Then why there is difference in Moderators ? Is it something to do with use of Uranium 235

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressurized_heavy-water_reactor

@JonCuster Thanks for the article, i have read that already. It talks about PHWR, i am asking for HWR. If PWR exist then why HWR

For the same reason - less neutron absorption in the moderator so you can use lower enriched (or not enriched) fuel. Pressurized vs not pressurized is irrelevant to the fission reactions and the neutron economy.
